# Issues with ellipsis (...) in filename when pulling files using ADB on Windows

Tags: adb, windows, files

I'm trying to pull files from the `/sdcard` partition of my phone to Windows 10 using ADB, and it errors:

```
cannot create [ my file > my computer ]: Not a directory
```

This only occurs at a particular folder "Meanwhile In Burbank...", which is copied as "Meanwhile In Burbank" (no ...), then errors out.

Any advice on how to handle ellipses?

Comment: Is the ellipsis made from three dots (like ...) or from a single character (like …)?

Comment: Suppose I should have clarified: three dots.

Comment: And the operating system from where you launch adb is a flavor of Windows, I guess. Correct?

Comment: Added computer OS and adb version to question.

Comment: I did a few tests on Windows 7, and was able to reproduce a behavior similar to yours. Actually, it's not ADB, but Windows' fault. The OS itself doesn't allow a file or a folder's name which ends with a period, and without anything after it. I assume you do know that a period delimits the extension in a file, so basically Windows doesn't allow a file or folder to end with an "empty" extension (which is different from not having an extension) and therefore trims the period(s).